# Load balancer and http download streams on docker swarm

Tags: docker, load-balancing, docker-swarm

I have put together an architecture that at high level is best described below

- Five node docker swarm cluster
- Have say 5 instances of my dockerized micro service running one copy on each of the swarm nodes
- The service offers functionality via REST end points
- One such functionality is downloads and they work perfectly, I wrote some code in Scala/Play framerwork, dockerized the service and deployed it.
- I also know that since I use swarm , it internally does LB per request for me.

I have some questions on WebSocket and how load balancer does not ruin things during download.

1. I start a 5GB file download and it works. I am using HTTP stream or chunked I guess it does not matter. Now my question is once my REST end point for download is hit, the TCP connection remains open and since it is open until the server closes the connection, it is due to this that the swarm load balancing does not interfere? In short, each time a client requests a HTTP call, swarm load balances it but once the TCP socket is established as in case of specific download example, the request is served by one node as the connection is not re-stablished during the download process?
2. If a client opens a web socket, it will hit one of the nodes of swarm where the service is running and the websocket connection since it is open, the same service instance will push the notifications?
3. If for some reason the websocket dies, a new connection might be established by client but the request might end up on some other service instance and will remain like that until a new connection is again established?

Are above 3 points correct in my understanding? Is there some reading material/blogs I can find more on elaborating this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using nginx like proxy LB, ip_hash mode

*Specifies that a group should use a load balancing method where requests are distributed between servers based on client IP addresses. The first three octets of the client IPv4 address, or the entire IPv6 address, are used as a hashing key. The method ensures that requests from the same client will always be passed to the same server except when this server is unavailable. In the latter case client requests will be passed to another server. Most probably, it will always be the same server as well.*

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ip_hash